# Animate background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am learning to use jquery to achieve this [BUY IT button](http://mobilehub.theshop.ph/mobilehub/Lg-G2-32gb/p-53e9e12cbc86751b52b5e715) and this is my attempt so far:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").hover(

function(){
    $("a").animate({'backgroundColor': '#3D977D'},400);
},
function(){
    $("a").animate({'backgroundColor': '#367603'},400);
}
); 
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c3uwtyfg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery internally doesn't have animation for color, but you can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) library to add this feature to jQuery animate function.

**[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c3uwtyfg/1/)**

You can download [jquery-ui.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js).
So your code after including jQueryUI wont change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("a").hover(
        function() {
            $("a").animate({'backgroundColor': '#3D977D'},400);
        }, function() {
            $("a").animate({'backgroundColor': '#367603'},400);
        }
    ); 
});
```

---

**EDIT:** You need to animate the div up to down. I've written a simple example for you:  **[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/j640h8na/)**

```
$(function(){ 
      $('.btn').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.cover').stop().animate({top:0},200);
      },function(){
        $(this).find('.cover').stop().animate({top:-40},200);
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what i want to achieve: http://mobilehub.theshop.ph/mobilehub/Lg-G2-32gb/p-53e9e12cbc86751b52b5e715

Comment: @user3336090 This is totally something else and it's not about animating colors. This can be done by animating a div.

Comment: If so, how? animating colors using jquery ui is cool tho, something to brag to my classmates haha

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't animate colors. jQuery UI [adds the ability](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) to do so, or you can just use [the plugin they use](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/), or there are other standalone plugins that do it, but the base library does not.

Comment: someone said that it is totally something else and it's not about animating colors, this can be done animating a div. this is what i want to achieve: http://mobilehub.theshop.ph/mobilehub/Lg-G2-32gb/p-53e9e12cbc86751b52b5e715 (the BUY IT button)